# US Short Term Rental - Can You Deduct The Full Property Depreciation And Property Taxes For A Primary Residence?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, tax-deduction, rental-property, property-taxes

I have a primary residence where I am domiciled and file my taxes.  I am on the road for work during most of the year and will rent out my residence via Airbnb when I am away.  I know that I can depreciate the property value part of my residence over 27.5 years and then I can deduct the property taxes as an expense.

Since I am still living at my residence when I am in town, do I get to deduct the full value of the property depreciation and property taxes or can I only deduct the proportion of those expenses for when I am not at home?

For example, let's say I live in the residence for 7 months and rent it out for 4 months and it sits empty for another month.  My yearly property depreciation is $20,000 and my property taxes are $10,0000.  Can I deduct the full $30,000 as an expense or can I only deduct $12,500 ($30,000 x (5 months / 12 months))?

Answer (score 3):

You prorate the deduction based on the business use days. For the days when the property is not available for rent you cannot deduct the expenses. See the [IRS Publication 527](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p527#en_US_2022_publink1000219175).